# Real time audio manipulating

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe3, firemonkey-fm2

I have a lesson at university where we explore Embercader RAD Studio XE3. We try to find a Firemonkey or VCL component/library what alows us audio munipulating such as sampling or manipulating realtime microfone source.

Every help are appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`AudioLab`](http://www.mitov.com/products/audiolab#overview) components from [mitov Software](http://www.mitov.com).